# Something wrong while using crypt function in C

Tags: c, encryption, cs50

I am using the crypt function in C, where I am giving the command line input an encrypted word. I use the words in /usr/share/dict/words and encrypt them using the crypt function and then compare the encrypted output of the crypt function with the command line input. If the words are the same, then I give out the non-encrypted code as the output using a printf statement.
The code is given below.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define _XOPEN_SOURCE
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<cs50.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int
    main(int argc, string argv[]){
    char line[80];
    string crypto;
    if(argc>2||argc<2)
     {
     printf("ERROR. Enter only one crypt");
     return 1;
     }
    string crypti=argv[1];
    FILE *fr;
    string as;
    fr=fopen("/usr/share/dict/words","r");
    if(!fr)
        {
      printf("File can't be read");
      exit(-1);
        }
    while(fgets(line,80,fr)!=NULL)
      {
      as=crypt(line,"50");
      if(strcmp(as,crypti)==0)
       {
     printf("%s",line);
      break;
       }
       }
    fclose(fr);
   }
```

The code seems to work fine just for 1 input i.e when I give "./a.out 50q.zrL5e0Sak"(without quotes). However, if I use any other input for the crypt, the code seems to fail. Another example for password:encrypted password is abaca:50TZxhJSbeG1I. The word abaca is present in the list but fails to identify. I am not able to fix this code to work for all inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following snippet to the beginning of `while (fgets...)` body:

```
  size_t len = strlen(line);
  if (len)
    line[len-1]='\0';
```

There is usually a newline `\n` (when it was read) in the end of the buffer read by `fgets`.

Your original code works with `"password"` because only 8 first characters of the key are actually used by `crypt`. It would work with any word of length 8 or more as well.

Also, make sure that the output is flushed after you print the result, by adding a newline to your format string or (if you don't want to output an extra newline) calling `fflush(stdout)`:

```
printf("%s\n",line);
/* or */
printf("%s",line);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work for 8 characters or more. But still am not able to get it to work for less than 8 characters.

Comment: It works for me (I have no "abaca" in `/usr/share/dict/words`, but *abacus* is there and is found for `508kXyEKZ232U`). Maybe your shell prompt makes it hard to see your output if it's not ended by newline: try adding `\n` to your format string.

Comment: It seems to be working after I use the fflush(stdout). Thanks a lot.